# accessing a variable inside a method from another class using java

Tags: java

i want to access a variable inside another class

```
public class ephem_t{
  public static void robel(){
    int vflg;
    Calendar t;
    int iodc;
}
}
```

and i want to use the variables inside another class

```
public class testRobel{
  public static void readfile(){
    ????????
}
}
```

i want to do like

```
public class testRobel{
      public static void readfile(){
    ephem_t eph = new ephem_t();
    eph.robel.vflg = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: class variables are not declared in a method.

Comment: Local variables of a method are not accessible outside the method.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your class variables outside of a method, just

```
public class ephem_t {
    int vflg;
    Calendar t;
    int iodc;
}
```

And an option is to use `setters & getters` to access those variables.

Or jus create a new `object` of your class.

```
public class testEphm_t {
    public static void readfile(){
        ephem_t eph = new ephem_t();
        eph.vflg = 1;
    }
}
```